# Gmail API の User-rate limit exceeded エラー発生原因に関して

Tags: api, gmail

GMail APIを利用しているのですが、User-rate limit exceeded が発生します。
発生前の状態をAPI Managerで、リクエスト数等から、「Daily Usage」,「Per User Rate Limit」共に、quotaの計算を行ってみても、上限を超えていないように見えます。
　※エラー発生前の数日間はsendに関するAPIメソッドも記録されていません。

Gmail APIのquota上限の変更や、API以外からの影響など有るのでしょうか？

判断基準ですが、仮説レベルですが下記のように計算判断しました。

トラフィックデータからピーク時のリクエスト状況を確認すると
秒間で最大リクエストが30件で、通常20件弱で推移していているとします。

APIメソッドの種類を見ると、１分平均ですが
messages.get:27.617件
messages.list:0.6167件
history.list:0.1167件
labels.list:0.2667件
getProfile:0.1167件
messages.delete:0件（約2日に1回）
messages.modify:0件（約1日1回）
messages.send:0件（約1日2回）

それぞれquotaは、下記
messages.get :5
messages.list:5
history.list:2
labels.list :1
getProfile:1
messages.delete:10
messages.modify:5
messages.send:100

上記から、getで30件分を加算すると、秒間 150quotaで、
仮にsend1件，delete1件を加えても250quotaとなり、
APIの秒間quota制限を超えないと判断しまし‌​た。

１日のリクエスト総数からdailyのquota制限は原因ではなく、
秒間のquota制限が原因ではないかと思っているのですが、
ほとんど、messages.getしか実施していない割に、
User-rate limit exceededが発生することが多いので、
質問させていただきました。

追記
API Managerのダッシュボードで、GmailAPIの「割り当て」画面で「Queries per day」,「Queries per 100 second」を見ても、まだまだ、上限まで余裕がある状態が続いていますが、
毎日、エラーが発生しています。

5分毎にGmaiAPIの呼び出しを行っており、 5分毎に20件程度のリクエストが発生しています。（今現在の1日分だと316,436回）

Comment: 何をどう計算して何と比べて「超えていない」と判断したのか具体的に書いてください。確認漏れかもしれませんし計算間違いかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
判断基準ですが、仮説レベルですが下記のように計算判断しました。
トラフィックデータからピーク時のリクエスト状況を確認すると
秒間で最大リクエストが30件で、通常20件弱で推移していているとします。
APIメソッドの種類を見ると、１分平均ですが
messages.get:27.617件
messages.list:0.6167件
history.list:0.1167件
labels.list:0.2667件
getProfile:0.1167件
messages.delete:0件（約2日に1回）
messages.modify:0件（約1日1回）
messages.send:0件（約1日2回）

それぞれquotaは、下記
messages.get :5
messages.list:5
history.list:2
labels.list :1
getProfile:1
messages.delete:10
messages.modify:5
messages.send:100

上記から、getで30件分を加算すると、秒間 150qで、仮にsend1件，delete1件を加えても250qとなり、APIの秒間quota制限を超えないと判断しました。

Comment: コメントに書かれると非常に見難いので、質問に必要な情報は質問文を編集する形で追記してください。

Comment: 「通常20件弱」というのは1日にわたってでしょうか？1日あたりの呼び出し件数を追記できますか

Comment: @suzukis 様、コメントありがとうございます。 5分毎にGmaiAPIの呼び出しを行っており、
5分毎に20件程度のリクエストが発生しています。（今現在の1日分だと316,436回）

Comment: 宛先にGoogleのグループ(メーリングリスト)が含まれていませんか？　グループ宛てにメールを送ると、送信件数はグループメンバーの数になるので、頻繁に使うと一日の上限に達したという経験をしたことがあります。

Comment: @Fumu 7 様、貴重な情報ありがとうございます。本件に関しては、送信に関しては、グループの利用も無さそうですので、Bandwidth Limitsを調べてみようと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

Gmail APIの制限は制限はAPI呼び出し回数の他に

- Mail Sending Limits
- Bandwidth Limits
- Concurrent Requests

があります。[リファレンス](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)

このうち、上2つが超過時に`User-rate limit exceeded`となることになっています。

送信はほとんど無いと言うことなので、Bandwidth Limitsではないでしょうか。

「1日分だと316,436回」だとすると1回あたり8KBぐらいが限界という計算になります。

Comment: 様 、情報ありがとうございます。確かにBandwidth Limitsが、疑わしいのでテストを実施してみます。 ただ、こちらの都合で申し訳ないのですが、他の作業との兼ね合いで結果を反映するまで少し日にちか掛かりそうです。分かり次第、反映いたします。ありがとうございます。